# Solving Trignometric integral with the aid of residues.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are real numbers such that $\alpha^2> \beta^2+\gamma^2$ show that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\alpha+\beta \cos \theta +\gamma \sin \theta} = \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2}}\frac{|\alpha|}{\alpha}.$$

My attempt: change the variable $z = e^{i\theta}$, i.e.   $\cos \theta = \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}, \sin \theta =   -i\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2}$ in the given integral to obtain $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\alpha+\beta \cos \theta +\gamma \sin \theta} = 2\int_{C} \frac{-iz^{-1} \times z\, dz}{2\alpha z+\beta(z^2+1)-i\gamma(z^2-1)}\\ = 2\int_{C} \frac{-i\, dz}{z^2(\beta-i\gamma)+2\alpha z+\beta+i \gamma} $$where $C$ is unit circle. Further, from above integral we get $$= \frac{-2i}{\beta-i\gamma}\int_{C} \frac{dz}{\bigg(z+\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma}\bigg) \bigg(z+\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma}\bigg)}  $$ $$= -\iota \frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2}}\bigg[ \int_{C} \frac{dz}{\bigg(z+\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma}\bigg) }- \int_{C} \frac{dz}{ \bigg(z+\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma}\bigg)} \bigg]$$
How to proceed forward? Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: let the following contour integrals defined in the boundary of the unit disk in the complex plane (traveled in counter clock-wise direction):

$$\oint \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)}=\oint\frac{A}{z-a}\, dz+\oint\frac{B}{z-b}\, dz$$

for some constants $A,B\in\Bbb C$. Now use the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: How to look for the modulus of zeros of denominator and decide whether they are in unit circle or not?

Comment: @MittalG you need to show if $$\left|\frac{\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2}}{\beta-i\gamma}\right|^2=\frac{(\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2})^2}{\beta^2+\gamma^2}<1^2$$ holds for some of the roots, then apply Cauchy integral formula

Comment: $(\frac{\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma})(\frac{\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2-\gamma^2)}}{\beta-i\gamma}) = 1$  One of them is inside $|z|= 1$ and one is outside.

Comment: @Doug M: Product is not one.

Comment: @MittalG you are right, the product is not 1, however the absolute value of the product is 1, hence if the absolute value of one of the roots is less than 1 then necessarily the absolute value of the other root is bigger than 1