# calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)+c}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the following integral when $a^2+b^2=1<c$  :
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{acos(t)+bsin(t)+c}$
I thought maybe setting $\cos(t)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2},\sin(t)=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$ and then try to calculate but not sure about if it's the right way to do ti

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)+c}dt$ with $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1<c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760900/integrating-int-02-pi-frac1a-costb-sintcdt-with-sqrta2b2-1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3020185, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229374 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cfrac%7Bdt%7D%7Ba%5Ccos(t)%2Bb%5Csin(t)%2Bc%7D%24&p=1)